# euca-* commands xml responses

Tags: xml, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-web-services, eucalyptus

I want to watch the XML response returned by euca-* requests. Do any one know how can I watch them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interacting with Eucalyptus, the service is running on port 8773, so you could use something like

ngrep -d  port 8773

on the machine you are running the commands. You need to be root on that machine.

Comment: Actually I made the same idea and used wireshark to monitor the requests and the xml response and it worked well